# Laravel 4: Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in my app im uploading files and saving them in the database (the path not the image itself), in my view I want to display a link for each file in my table when click on the link it should take to a function in the controller that returns a Response::download right?

here's my view, im sending the id of the file on the route

```
@extends('layouts.adminbase')
@section('content')
    @foreach($files as $file)   
        <div class = "row fondue">
            <h3><div class="col-md-12"><b><?php echo link_to("/home/download/".$file->id,$file->name)?> </b></div></h3>                 
        </div>          
    @endforeach

@stop
```

here's my route

```
Route::get('/home/download/{id}','HomeController@downloadfile')->before('auth');
```

and here's my downloadfile function

```
public function downloadfile($id)
{
    $file = DB::table('documents')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
    return Response::download($file->route);
```

the view works fine, but when clicking on one of the links it shows this error

```
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)
```

not sure why im getting this error....  I do enabled the php_fileinfo in php.ini on my wamp server....

Comment: Which php.ini did you edit?  On WAMP, the one the webserver is using will be found in `bin/apache/php.ini`.

Comment: also, what version of php are you running?

Comment: im using php 5.4.12

the one im editing is located in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12/php.ini

Comment: Try using phpinfo() to double check php_fileinfo is actually enabled.

Comment: you were right...i edited the one in the apache folder and it works perfect...thanx

Comment: it's will help you to solving your issue
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23431224/4499691