# Mime type error laravel

Tags: mime-types, laravel-4.2

I'm working in laravel and i'm getting error while uploading image file.
Following is the error message:

> Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

Any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found same problem here.

This link might help.

[Laravel 4 - no guessers available issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065703/laravel-4-no-guessers-available-issue)

It says uncomment "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" from php.ini and restart server it will solve your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by working on FTP server ? 
You mean, You can't uncomment "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" ?